# How do I simulate a deadlock in MySql without programming scripts?

Tags: mysql, deadlock

It's sometimes useful to be able to simulate a deadlock in a database (such as MySQL) for testing purposes. If you have write access to the database, you can simulate the deadlock by starting a write transaction on a table another query will attempt to use.

Answer (score 0):

1. Log onto the database
2. Start a transaction
   `begin;`
3. Lock the table with an update statement that modifies all rows in the table
   `update <table> set <column>=<value>;`
4. All other applications will encounter the table as being locked until you commit or rollback the transaction.
5. To end the deadlock, rollback the transaction.
   `rollback;`